# Vercel and Nextjs: redirect subdomain to path dynamically

Tags: url, url-rewriting, next.js, vercel

I have a nextjs project with a `:client` param which represents a client, like this:

`domain.com/:client`

And I have multiple clients... so I need to do this rewrite:

`:client.domain.com` -> `domain.com/:client`

For example for clients:

- google.domain.com -> domain.com/google
- netflix.domain.com -> domain.com/netflix

...

Inside the same project.

Any way to do that?

Comment: Did you try this? `{
  "redirects": [
    { "source": "/(.*).domain.com ", "destination": "domain.com/$1" }
  ]
}`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `redirects` option in the `vercel.json`, as Maxime mentioned.

However, it requires 1 extra key.

For example, if your app is available at `company.com`:

```json
{
  ...
  redirects: [
    {
      "source": "/",
      "has": [
        {
          "type": "host",
          "value": "app.company.com"
        }
      ],
      "destination": "/app"
    }
  ]
}
```

More info:

- [Example Guide](https://vercel.com/guides/can-i-redirect-from-a-subdomain-to-a-subpath)
- [`vercel.json` docs](https://vercel.com/docs/project-configuration#project-configuration/redirects)

Answer (score 1):

Create a config in your project root with next.config.js

If this file exists add the following snippet to it, Mind you, we used example.com in place of domain .com as Body cannot contain "http://domain. com" in stackoverflow

// next.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/:path*",
        has: [
          {
            type: "host",
            value: "client.example.com",
          },
        ],
        destination: "http://example.com/client/:path*",
        permanent: false,
      },
    ];
  },
};
```

To confirm it's also working in development, try with localhost

```
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,

  // async rewrites() {
  async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/:path*",
        has: [
          {
            type: "host",
            value: "client.localhost",
          },
        ],
        destination: "http://localhost:3000/client/:path*",
        permanent: false,
      },
    ];
  },
};
```

#### Dynamic Redirect

To make it dynamic, we'll create an array of subdomains

```
const subdomains = ["google", "netflix"];

module.exports = {
  async redirects() {
    return [
      ...subdomains.map((subdomain) => ({
        source: "/:path*",
        has: [
          {
            type: "host",
            value: `${subdomain}.example.com`,
          },
        ],
        destination: `https://example.com/${subdomain}/:path*`,
        permanent: false,
      })),
    ];
  },
}
```

You can read more from the official next.js doc [redirects](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/redirects) or [rewrite](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites)